Android studio gradle sync library download failed
My Android project suddenly started failing. On one of my projects, I used the following two libraries.


tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-java:0.8.8 (https://github.com/bilibili/ijkplayer)
jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2 (https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations)



Gradle version: 8.9 | Gradle plugin version: 8.2.2 | JVMv Target = 17

My project was running fine then suddenly my gradle sync started failing due to these libraries.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-java:0.8.8.
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :app


There were no code changes but I updated android studio to the latest version.

Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 1 Build
#AI-242.23339.11.2421.12483815, built on October 11, 2024 Runtime version: 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
by JetBrains s.r.o. Toolkit: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit Windows 11.0

I suspected it was an issue with the IDE, so I uninstalled and downgraded it, but this did not resolve the problem. I tested the same branch on another device, and it worked. And the problem does not exist in my coworker's system.
I could not discover a solution on the internet, and AI models are not helpful right now. It is been days since I was stuck on this problem. I tried disabling Windows firewalls. I tried various Gradle versions, Java versions, and Android Studio versions.
I ended up resetting my machine and reinstalling Android Studio, and it still did not work.
Please help!
Edit 2
After checking mvnrepository and following David Wasser's answer the above libraries and versions are found in the following repos.

https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/
https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/

So, I've updated my settings.gradle file.
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url 'https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/' }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/' }
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/' }
    }
}

When I do a gradle build with these changes, it's still failing with the below error.
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-java:0.8.8.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-java:0.8.8.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/tv/danmaku/ijk/media/ijkplayer-java/0.8.8/ijkplayer-java-0.8.8.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/tv/danmaku/ijk/media/ijkplayer-java/0.8.8/ijkplayer-java-0.8.8.pom'. Received status code 401 from server:
   > Could not resolve jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Could not resolve jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/jp/wasabeef/glide-transformations/2.0.2/glide-transformations-2.0.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/jp/wasabeef/glide-transformations/2.0.2/glide-transformations-2.0.2.pom'. Received status code 401 from server:


Tell me where you downloaded it from if the problem is solved?

I couldn't download it. But I found that one of my systems has the library in its Gradle cache. I got it from there and added it to the project's libs.

Looks like ijkplayer is hosted at Mulesoft:
https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/
and glide-transformations version 2.0.2 is only available at Spring Lib M:
https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/
You would need to have both of these repository links in your gradle file (usually in settings.gradle) otherwise gradle won't be able to find these artifacts.
Sometimes artifacts are removed (especially if they are old) from the usual respositories, so these may have been recently deleted. You may have had local copies of these libraries in your gradle cache up until now.
See also Commonsware blog article about disappearing artifacts: https://commonsware.com/blog/2024/10/16/hey-where-artifacts-go.html

maven { url 'https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/' }
maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/' }

I've added this to my setting.gradle, still doesn't work. I've checked mvnrepository and tried other versions. Still doesn't work.

when you say "doesn't work", that's not helpful. Please edit your post and show the error messages that get logged. It should list the respository links it tried to use and why they failed.

Please check the edited question.

Hmmm. You could try using glide-transformation version 4.3.0 this is available on maven central. The other library I found it here: https://repository.axelor.com/nexus/service/rest/repository/browse/maven-public/tv/danmaku/ijk/media/ijkplayer-java/0.8.8/ just download the AAR and put it in your libs directory and then add a local reference so gradle will use it from your local file system. This stuff is really old so you should probably look for more recent alternatives.

I'll have to be more careful about including old libraries in the future. But for now, my issue has been resolved. Thank you so much for the help.

Good to hear. How did you finally solve it?
